# Recursive method that adds elements to list

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I would like to get the list of all sub-directories of a folder, including the nested ones.
Therefore, I would like to have a `list<Folder> myList` that will be filled by a recursive method.

```
 void myMethod(?)  
 {
   list<Folder> listFolders = ...  ;
   foreach (Folder curFolder in listFolders)
      {
        myList.add(curFolder);
      }
 }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Where does myList comes from? What do you want to achieve with recursion (and why, because it doesn't look necessary)

Comment: what's the point you want to do? you should give a better example, but with the given example that makes no sense for me (even the use of recursion)

Comment: @samy, `myList` is a list that I would like to be declared out of the method. This is the list that at the end of method should be filled. The recursion purpose is similar for getting list of all nested directories of a folder. Any ideas?

Comment: added a solution, first example is with recursion, 2nd without

Comment: use subfolder method

Comment: @gasroot, The folder is just for demonstration :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Declare a function like this

```
List<Folder> ListFolders(Folder initialFolder)
{
    var folders = new List<Folder>();
    folder.Add(initialFolder);
    foreach (var f in initialFolder.GetSubFolders())
    {
        folders.AddRange(ListFolders(f));
    }
    return folders;
}
```

The `Folder` class is left to you as an exercice, it will have to contain the name of the current folder, and a method to get its subfolders (hint: look into the `System.IO.Directory` class)

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            List<string> dirs = new List<string>();
            addDirectoryToList(@"C:\exampledir\", dirs);
    }

    void addDirectoryToList(string dir, List<string> list)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            addDirectoryToList(subdir.FullName, list);
        }
    }
```

or without recursion:

```
    void addDirectoryToList(string dir, List<string> list)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        list.Add(dir);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            list.Add(subdir.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an extension method that selects from an IEnumerable Recursively:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> recursiveSelector)
        {
            foreach (var i in source)
            {
                yield return i;

                var directChildren = recursiveSelector(i);
                var allChildren = SelectRecursive(directChildren, recursiveSelector);

                foreach (var c in allChildren)
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }
```

You can use it to create a "flat" enumerable out of every hierarchy. Assume the Folder class has a property that returns its direct children: as follows:

```
public class Folder 
{
    public IEnumerable<Folder> Children {get;}
}
```

You will be able to get a flat list of sub folders with the following line:

```
var flatList = folder.SelectRecursive(f => f.Children).ToList();
```

Hope that this is what you mean.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I look for. What do you mean in `(f => f.Children)`?

Comment: The SelectRecursive method takes one parameter which is a function that it should use in order to get from one item to its direct children. This is the syntax that allows to pass a function as parameter. The term "f => f.Children" is compiled into a function that when called returns with parameter f returns f.Children. If you want to learn more about this notation google up "Lambda expressions in C#" and "Anonymous methods in C#". Its a whole topic, a rather interesting one :-)